# Visual Studio 2013 database project- DROP objects in target but not in project

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio, deployment, visual-studio-2013

I am using VS 2013 for database project. I want to drop ojected from target db which are not in db project including table and SP's. I have checked property "DROP objects in target but not in project" but it doesn't work. I still see table in target which is not part of db solution. I do not see any warnings either and btw table is empty so it should be dropped without warnings anyway. I have used same option in older version of Visual studio and it worked.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a long time coming to answer the question, but this is how I resolved the problem.  I simply opened the SQL File TableName.sql

1. Ctrl+a (aka select all)
2. Compare
3. It will show the file with an action to delete in the compare
4. Update
5. Delete the file from Visual Studio 2013 project